# How to design for scalable set operations?

Tags: sql, performance, database-design, scalability

This is the requirement for an educational application to teach words to language learners:

1. Learner can declare that he/she knows a given word
2. Learner can memorize the given word (to be managed by the application later)
3. Learner can choose to ignore the given word, so that it won't be given to him/her later
4. Admin can ignore a word in general, so that it won't be given to any learner
5. A list of words exist in database, as the reference
6. Next word to be given to the student, should be new to him/her

This is our design:

```
Words
    - Id
    - Word
    - Meaning
    - PartOfSpeech

LearnerWords
    - Id
    - LearnerId
    - WordId
    - TypeOfInteraction (ignored, memorized, memorizing, reviewing, etc.)

Learners
    - Id
    - Name
```

And this is a pseudo-query that we execute to find the next new word for a given learner:

```
select top 1 * 
from Words 
where Id not in 
(
    select WordId 
    from LearnerWords
    where LearnerId = @learnerId
)
```

Of course the overall design and query is much more complex and more details are in action in selecting next new word for a given learner.

Now, imagine that words list contains 100K words, and a learner has already learnt more than 5K words. Using the given query, this gets slower and slower and slower by more learners learning more words.

Is there a better design for these types of business requirements? How to design for scale in this case?

Comment: How many learners there will be in the database?

Comment: A million records exist in database

Comment: The search for the next word is based on some specific criterion or it is casual (as it seems from your query)?

Answer (score 1):

For your `LearnerWords` table, I suggest you replace the `TypeOfInteraction` column with a set of nullable date columns which indicate when each interaction occurred or started (or null if it hasn't), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `LearnerWords` (
    `LearnerId`  int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `WordId`  int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `Ignored`  datetime NULL ,
    `Memorized`  datetime NULL ,
    `Memorizing`  datetime NULL ,
    `Reviewing`  datetime NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`LearnerId`, `WordId`)
);
```

This reduces your table from a row per learner/word/interaction to one per learner/word while at the same time recording more information.

**About your query:**

Be careful with `NOT IN` and subqueries (or any dynamic set of values).  `NOT IN` returns `NULL` if the set it checks is empty or contains only `NULL`s, meaning that for learners who don't have any records in `LearnerWords`, your query won't return any results.

A better approach is to use a `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Words w
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM LearnerWords lw
    WHERE lw.LearnerId = @learnerId
      AND lw.WordId = w.WordId
)
```

Note also dcieslak's answer - indexing is essential for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just create index in LearnerWords on LearnerID (plus maybe TypeOfInteraction in  composite index) and it supposed to be fast. Your database query optimization engine will figure out that you just need 1 row and it will use index to access required data very fast.

Comment: I think `not in` clause is what the OP is concerned about. Seems that he's right. The given query for a database of 1 learner, and overall 100 words works hugely different from the same query run on a database of 1 million users, 100K words, and each user knowing at least 5K words. That means in `not in` clause with 5K items.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I don't know op's db vendor. The most of db is able to optimize it and it will not scan 5k rows. I.e. on MSSql add `SET STATISTICS IO ON` before query and check the result.

Comment: Basically db will optimize the query to use left anti semi join with stop condition after finding the first rows.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on actual used DBMS. Some of them will optimize the query one way, some - by another. Most of times you won't lose in execution speed by using anti join pattern:

```
select top 1 w.*
from Words w
left join LearnerWords lw on lw.LearnerId = @learnerId and lw.WordId = w.Id
where lw.WordId is null
```